# Visual Basic Compiling EXE... How do i include dependencies?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, compilation, exe

I have made a program in Visual Basic which connects to my MySQL server, asks for the password and checks it to the username...

Not very secure, as i learned how to use a database yesterday(i had never touched it before...).

Now, when i try to compile to an exe, gets it from the release folder, and puts the release folder on my other PC, it is missing the MySQL.Data, which i had to add as referance in visual basic...

Is there any way I can include dependencies in my Exe/Release? This will of course apply to all dependencies!

BTW, i am using Visual Basic 2010 Express!

Comment: Check your tags: vba <> vb.net.  vba is a language similar to vb.net but it is specifically for the office applications.  You will get better help with vb.net instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding reference, go to `Solution Explorer` window, expand `References`, click on `MySql.Data` to select. Go to `Properties` window and set `Copy local` property to `True`. After next build, you will get missing MySQL.Data.Dll in build folder. Then you can copy .exe and .dll to other PC.